# What are down sides of using ZeroMQ for sending large messages (up to gigabytes)?

Tags: zeromq, messaging

I found that people don't recommend sending large messages with ZeroMQ. But it is a real headache for me to split the data (it is somewhat twisted). Why this is not recommended is there some specific reason? Can it be overcome?

Comment: Pretty self evident. Why would you want to send a gigabyte message?

Comment: Data contains molecules and bonds between them - it is like an instance of matter in particular moment in time. We can split it in multiple chunks but it will be of no use until everything is in clients hands and this complicates both server and client code - it needs to assemble it manually - we loose the benefit of messaging framework.

Comment: You should probably store that data somewhere and instead pass around a message with a hash pointing to it (content addressable store). Which is what @user3666197 mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this is not recommended?

Resources ...

Even the best Zero-Copy implementation has to have spare resources to store the payloads in several principally independent, separate locations:

```
|<fatMessageNo1>|
|...............|__________________________________________________________ RAM
|...............|<fatMessageNo1>|
|...............|...............|__________________Context().Queue[peerNo1] RAM
|...............|...............|<fatMessageNo1>|
|...............|...............|...............|________O/S.Buffers[L3/L2] RAM
```

---

### Can it be overcome?

Sure, do not send Mastodon-sized-GB+ messages. May use any kind of an off-RAM representation thereof and send just a lightweight reference to allow a remote peer to access such an immense beast.

---

### Many new questions added via comment:

> <sub>I was concern more about something like transmission failure: what will zeromq do (will it try to retransmit automatically, will it be transparent for me etc). RAM is not so crucial - servers can have it more than enough and service that we write is not intended to have huge amount of clients at the same time. The data that I talk about is very interrelated (we have molecules/atoms info and bonds between them) so it is impossible to send a chunk of it and use it - we need it all)) – [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455649/paul) [25 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452212/what-are-down-sides-of-using-zeromq-for-sending-large-messages-up-to-gigabytes/49456556?noredirect=1#comment85926611_49456556)</sub>

You may be already aware that ZeroMQ is working under a Zen-of-Zero, where also a zero-warranty got its place.

So, a ZeroMQ dispatched message will **either** be delivered "through"  error-free, or not delivered at all. This is a great pain-saver, as your code will receive only a fully-protected content atomically, so no tortured trash will ever reach your target post-processing. Higher level soft-protocol handshaking allows one to remain in control, enabling mitigations of non-delivered cases from higher levels of abstractions, so if your design apetite and deployment conditions permit, **one can harness a brute force and send whatever-`[TB]`-BLOBs**, at one's own risk of blocked both local and infrastructure resources, if others permit and don't mind ( ... but never on my advice :o) )

Error-recovery self-healing - from lost-connection(s) and similar real-life issues - is handled if configuration, resources and timeouts permit, so a lot of troubles with keeping L1/L2/L3-ISO-OSI layers issues are efficiently hidden from user-apps programmers.

Comment: I was concern more about something like transmission failure: what will zeromq do (will it try to retransmit automatically, will it be transparent for me etc). RAM is not so crucial - servers can have it more than enough and service that we write is not intended to have huge amount of clients at the same time. The data that I talk about is very interrelated (we have molecules/atoms info and bonds between them) so it is impossible to send a chunk of it and use it - we need it all))